# How to prove inverse property of $P = \{hk \mid h \in H, k \in K\}$ is a subgroup of G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with subgroups $H$ and $K$. If for every $g \in G$ and $k \in K$ we know that $g^{-1}kg \in K$, prove that $P$ is a subgroup of $G$, where $P = \{hk \mid h \in H, k \in K\}$.

I already proved the closure property but when I try to prove the inverse property, I end up with $ha^{-1} = hk^{-1}h^{-1}$!

Answer (score 1):

So $K\triangleleft G$.  Now $(hk)^{-1}=k^{-1}h^{-1}=h^{-1}hk^{-1}h^{-1}=h^{-1}k'\in P$.